# Delete does not ask for confirmation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When Delete button is clicked, the confirmation box should pop up if the selected node has child nodes. Otherwise, it should not do anything.

Right now, when I click on delete, it just deletes without confirming.

Here is the code:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btn_delete" runat="server" Height="32px" 
        onclick="btn_delete_Click"  OnClientClick = "return childnode();"                              
        Text="Delete" Visible="False"  />  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function childnode() {
            var treeViewData = window["<%=nav_tree_items.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];

            var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
            if (selectedNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
                return confirm("heloo");
            }
            return false;
        }                                        
    </script>
```

Comment: Please tag with appropriate asp-related tag.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in `childenode()` and find out if it was getting called and if it was, why it didn't go to the confirm prompt?  You have several places in that code where it could be failing - pretty hard for us to know which one it is.  You need to do some simple debugging and it will be obvious in a few minutes.  My favorite debugger is built into Chrome, but the Firebug add-in in Firefox works well too.  Also, I don't know ASP, but how is onclick different from OnClientClick?

Comment: I did set a breakpoint. But apparently, it does not even go there. It is unaffected.

Comment: Then, what's the difference between onclick and OnClientClick in ASP?  Is javascript going to btn_delete_Click, not childnode?

Comment: FYI, the StackOverflow community would appreciate it if you gave yourself a meaningful name that gives us a chance to remember who you are the next time you post or the next time our paths cross.  user1047883 is pseudo-anonymous as we have no chance of remembering who you are or any of your previous context.

Comment: What is inside the document.getElementById(?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to return `false` from the function if you don't want the button push to go through in some cases. Currently you are only returning a value from the function when calling `confirm`.

If one or both of the if conditions fail, add a `return false` if you don't want the event to bubble up activating the button/sending the form.

---

### Modification of your existing code

```
function childnode() {
    var treeViewData = window["<%=nav_tree_items.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
    if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {
        var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
        if (selectedNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
            return confirm("heloo");
        }   

        return false; // don't send form                                             
    }

    return false; // don't send form
}
```

---

### Is it still malfunctioning?

1. Make sure that the logic inside your function is accurate, webbrowsers will often fail silently when trying to get a property of an undefined variable.
2. In your definition of your button you have written `OnClientClick = "return childnode();"`, try changing this to `OnClientClick="return childnode();"` and see if that might solve the problem.
3. See if the event fires at all, `OnClientClick="alert(123);"`.

Comment: I edited it to only have one if statement, but it still does not work

Comment: I also added return false, as seen above

Comment: Read the comments on the question.  The main issue is that childnode() is not getting called.

Comment: @user1047883 are you sure that there is nothing going wrong inside of your function? Change the script to the contents of [this paste](http://ppst.me/ibgcEg), run it and see if anything is undefined that shouldn't be.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see nothing wrong with his asp:button declaration, unless.. of course, ASP.NET is picky regarding spaces around the equal sign.

Comment: If you know ASP (I don't), what's the deal with defining both an `onclick` and and an `onClientClick`?

Comment: @jfriend00 onclick is the name of the callback that will `runat="server"`, onClientClick is the callback the browser should execute upon press of the button.

Comment: I tried the following and it doesn't work as well: OnClientCLick = "return childnode();" function childnode() { return confirm changes();}

Comment: Yup that works... and this one works as well: OnClientClick="return confirm(123);" But it does not work when it is called from a function

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your function, did you try out the paste I provided you with? I'm not surprised that `function childnode () {return confirm changes();}` didn't work, that is far from proper syntax.

Comment: yes I pasted the exact same code that you provided. But still no luck.

Comment: I meant i tried function childnode () {return confirm('save changes?');}

Comment: it works now! The problem was i put the script in the wrong place.

Comment: But the only problem is that it is not recognizing the childnodes. When there is only parent node in the tree view it displays the confirmation when it should only display it if the parent node has child nodes

Answer (score 0):

Your function have `return` not in all of it's parts. Probably your function exists without confirm. Review your logic and decide what you want to do if one of your `if` statements not passed.

Comment: Read the comments on the question.  The main issue is that childnode() is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
onclick="btn_delete_Click"  OnClientClick = "return childnode();"
```

To this:

```
onclick="btn_delete_Click;return childnode();"
```